# No funds being added to new Paypal Sandbox accounts in Developer Beta

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've added a new Business account and two new Personal accounts in Paypal Developer (the new one), and no funds have been added to the accounts. When I try to use them in my development process by signing in, once I've logged in, Paypal tells me that I need to add a credit card to continue with the payments.

I've also tried confirming the bank account through the sandbox account, and it comes up with the error `Sorry - your last action could not be completed`.

I can't complete the debug process without funds in the sandbox account, of course. But nothing I try will put any funds into the test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Business or Personal account in the Sandbox you have the option for selecting whether or not it has a credit card and bank account added to it. I would recommend selecting them when you create the account or they would need to be manually added and confirmed.

Navigating within a Sandbox account to make changes to it can be difficult and there are a few known issues currently that redirect you to the Live site. Those should be resolved soon.